# Venues for publishing short papers in Statistics and Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, optimization

Where can I publish really short papers( like 2 pages) in Statistics and Machine learning fields?

Comment: [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/archive/stat) would be fine.